# Javascript bitwise reset value

Tags: javascript

I have

```
bit1 =1
bit2 =2
bit3 =4 
etc...
```

I want to store 0 or 1 (false o true) at bit2,
so :

```
my_value=0;
mydata |=bit2*myvalue;
```

or

```
my_value=1;
mydata |=bit2*myvalue;
```

(my_value colud be some checkbox state)

My problem is that after having set mydata to 1 I cant set it to zero.
Bitwise  1 |= 0 is 1 ....

So I'd need a way to set a bit to zero. 
Is there any way to make this using without tricks?

The clear method force us to previously know the value ?
Any help w. be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, where `n` starts from 0 for the least significant bit:

To *set* bit `n` use `v |= (1 << n)`

To *clear* bit `n` use `v  &= ~(1 << n)`

To *toggle* bit `n` use `v ^= (1 << n)`

If you really want a one-liner to set a particular bit to either `true` or `false` (where the desired value is held in a variable) use:

```
v = (v & ~(1 << n)) | (value ? (1 << n) : 0);
```

i.e. clear the bit first, and then either set that bit or leave it as zero, or as a function:

```
function bitset(n, value) {
    var mask = 1 << n;   // NB: no range check
    if (value) {
        return n | mask;
    } else {
        return n & ~mask;
    }
}
```

Comment: So finally we have to write code.... I think somebody could to implement a 'reset' operator ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bit-wise AND operator `&`:

```
a &= 0;
// a is 0
```

Or simply set a new value to a:

```
a = 0;
// a is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I'd need a way to set a bit to zero. Is there any way to make this using without tricks?

If you know that the bit is set to 1, then you can always `XOR` it out:

```
mydata ^= bit2;
```

If you don't know, you have to use `AND` with the complement of your bit:

```
mydata &= (bit2 ^ -1)
mydata &= ~bit2
```